# findAll validates input fields

Tags: node.js, validation, sequelize.js

I have problems with findAll(), it "fires" validation and that makes problems when I want to select/find a row by ID using LIKE... For example the query would look like this

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id LIKE '%345%'

In my model the id column is set to INTEGER so I get error message that says:

"%345%" is not a valid integer

Is there a way to skip the validation when I use findAll etc. or is it a bad idea, does the validation maybe prevent SQL injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could form your where clause as follows

```
var id =345;
.findAll({where: ["id like ?", '%' + id + '%']});
```